# No such file or directory running Python in VS Code with WSL

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using VS Code with WSL on my PC, and whenever I try to run a Python file in VS Code, it gives me an error that no such directory or file is found.

I've set WSL as my default shell and the issue, of course, is that VS Code is feeding in the Windows-based path to the python script, without the /mnt/C/... that's needed when using WSL. Is there any way for me to set up VS Code so that I can automatically have VS Code feed in the right, WSL-based file paths (i.e., including the /mnt/C/...)?

Secondly, it also seems that when using the WSL terminal in VS Code, it's using Python 2.7. Since I've never installed Python 2.7 on my PC, I'm assuming it comes with the Linux distro I'm using. Is it also possible to set up VS Code so that even when using the WSL terminal, the python installation that's used is the one I've installed on Windows (which is actually part of an Anaconda distribution)?

Comment: I'd use remote development in vscode. That way you're running vscode like its actually on Linux.

Comment: I'm aware of that option, but it's not one that appeals to me as much. I'm still new to the world of software development, and so am not as comfortable with a pure CLI, Linux environment. I like to dabble with it via WSL, but I'd still rather stick to Windows in general. Remote development offers the opposite (Linux dev environment on Windows) of what I'm asking (Windows dev environment access via the Linux terminal).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to use the [Remote - WSL extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) so that VS Code treats your environment as Linux instead of as Windows.

As for reusing your Windows install of Python under WSL, I wouldn't try that as Python is compiled for a specific OS and thus makes assumptions that will break under another OS.